# Windows 8 WinRT Store App plagued by OData and MakePRI errors in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, odata

We are creating a Windows 8 Store app using Visual Studio 2012 which uses an online Azure database. In uni we work off Windows 8 machines and at home we work off Windows 8.1 machines with Resharper. Everyone on my team has begun receiving these errors recently, seemingly out of the blue:

- Processing Resources with error: Unspecified error - File: MakePri
  (**Pri** not PRI)
- Multiple entries of
  'Microsoft.Data.OData/DuplicatePropertyNamesChecker_MultipleLinksForSingleton'
  found. - File: MakePRI (**PRI** not Pri)

And in our unit test project:

- Processing Resources with error: Unspecified error - File: MakePri
  (**Pri** not PRI)
- C:\temp\resources.pri not found. (our build output is C:\temp for our main project and C:\temp\test for our unit tests as we work off networked drives in uni - if we have them building to the same folder we get another error about the appmanifest!)

[image: MakePRI error]

Our references in our main project (includes Microsoft.Data.OData):

[image: main project references]

Our references in our unit test project (does not include Microsoft.Data.OData):

[image: unit test references]

It seems to happen to each of us at different times and we can't seem to pinpoint any cause at all. Sometimes it will simply disappear, other times it will not. The only recent changes I can think of is that we recently added Callisto, but I can't see why that would cause such a strange problem.

The only results I have found when googling MakePri appear to be from developers having the same issue but because they are using different locales other than English ones - but we are not working on machines with any language other than English and are not using any languages other than English within our project.

**EDIT:** Removing and readding the reference has worked temporarily, although I have a feeling this error may crop up again.

Comment: Are you targeting Win 8.0? Per the Callisto docs, it says as of v1.4 they only support Win 8.1 apps.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately we have to target Windows 8 as per our assignment (semester started before 8.1 was out) and the uni machines only have Windows 8/VS 2012. Rolling out Windows 8 took weeks longer than expected and left us a few weeks behind all the other project teams so I can imagine that's why they're hesitant to roll out 8.1 as well.